# Nexus 7 with Ubuntu Touch stuck on Google screen

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I started to install the ubuntu touch image and once the ubuntu touch screen came up with the logo and one of the options was to restart, so I restarted it and now it is stuck on the Google screen. I have the Nexus 7. I can't try to install ubuntu or android on it now because it has to be on in order for me to use adb. Please help. Hope I didn't brick my Nexus 7

Comment: Have you tried holding the Volume down and power at the same time while turning it on?

Comment: I have. It will go into fastboot mode

Comment: you came use fastboot command to install a new rom `fastboot flash system /path/to/system.img`

Comment: Do you not have recovery installed? if so you can flash a new rom with the. This is the preferred way.

Comment: Also, if you do use the fastboot method, you will also have to wipe the other partitions before installing. `fastboot erase userdata`+ `fastboot erase cache` + `fastboot reboot`

Comment: Thanks for helping by the way. I just erased userdata and all and thn did the flash system. It went through and stayed at the fastboot and I hit start and it is still stuck at the Google screen. At the top of the Google screen it says "ubuntu touch B" in small white letter top left corner...

Comment: It is still stuck. Won't go anywhere from the Google Screen. I can still boot into fastboot

Comment: Try flashing with an android ROM, just to get the device back in a working state and then you can try and flash touch afterwards. There is obviously something wrong with the touch .img.

Comment: Thats what I did. Flashed the Android but still is stuck

Comment: what ROM did you use?

Comment: nakasig-jdq39-factory-0798439d.tgz

Comment: what I would do at this point is flash a recovery image using `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` Use this link to download the recovery [Nexus 7 Touch Recovery](http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-touch-6.0.3.1-grouper.img). Then download a rom: [Factory Images "nakasi" for Nexus 7 (Wi-Fi)](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/nakasi-jdq39-factory-c317339e.tgz). Boot to recovery and mount as usb storage. Copy the factory image rom to the sd card. Then use recovery to install zip from SD card. **Please Note: Android does NOT use.tgz file. only .img or .zip**

Comment: It says "Error mounting /sdcard

Comment: got the mounting of the sd card to work I guess because it didn't say error, but I can't see it on my ubuntu computer now

Comment: Can you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l`? It better to edit you question with the result as this space isn't meant for it. Thanks

Comment: WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Comment: Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  1953525167   976762583+  ee  GPT
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1: 8438 MB, 8438939648 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1025 cylinders, total 16482304 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x5b51e944

Disk /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Comment: If you open gparted, is it listed there? Is it an 8GB SD?

Comment: it is showing up in gparted. says /dev/sda3. 7.86 GB and says it's unknown.

Comment: ok can you format it to ext4 and then mount it. Copy the ROM .zip file over to it and "Install Zip from sd" in recovery. **Make sure it is the zip file you are coping over"

Comment: Sorry, I have just noticed the ROM you downloaded is a .tgz format. I don't think recovery will recognize this when installing zip from SD. try downloading this one: [Smooth Rom](http://goo.im/devs/SmoothROM/SmoothROM/SmoothROM-v5.2.zip). And just copy that straight to the SD. Sorry about that.

Comment: Tried to format and it says "error, if you want support, you need to provide the saved details" weird

Comment: yeah this is very weird. Do you have another method of writing to the SD Card like a SD slot or something like that? YOu can also try formatting it in Fat32 or NTFS As long as you can mount it in Ubuntu.

Comment: Problem is, the Nexus 7 tablet doesn't have a "real" sd card

Comment: OK leave the formatting and use the `fastboot flash system /path/to/system.img` command using the second link to a ROM I get you. You will need to unzip the file. I'm sure we'll get there. remember to use the `erase` commands before flashing

Comment: I actually already tried doing that as well and didn't work :( Also when I do it that way, it flashes real fast. Less than a minute. Don't think that seems right either

Comment: I was successful in formating the "sd card" as NTFS though

Comment: that is very quick for a flash.But if you can mount the card and copy the the zip file, then that seems to be the way forward. Hopefully it installs fine from recovery. Otherwise I am out of ideas.

Comment: Wow... Think it's working now. I was trying to do the image and not the zip file. Hope it works now. It is taking longer so looks like it might will :) Thanks

Comment: Think it is still stuck

Comment: What is it doing? What's on the screen? Sometimes it can take a while depending on the ROM. This is the method, so if the ROM doesn't work there are plenty on XDA.

Comment: If this has help, please don't forget to mark as answered, and accept answer. Thanks

Comment: Isn't working :( Sorry

Comment: what is it doing now?

Comment: still staying at the google screen

Comment: I tried to flash the ubuntu touch as well the same way as with the android, but it still isn't working

Comment: but you got the table to boot up with the android rom?

Comment: Got it on Android again. I was supposed to run ./flash-all.sh while device is in fastboot mode

Comment: I would suggest avoiding the igm you have for touch. maybe try another method or another img

Comment: @MichaelPlatt Can you please add the information to your question instead of the comments? It's hard to follow exactly what's going on here if the question is never updated!

Comment: I also got stuck on the Google splash screen and haven't been able to boot Ubuntu Touch. I managed to reinstall the stock android by downloading the stock android image from: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images#nakasig This downloads a tgz file, in my case called `nakasig-jdq39-factory-0798439d.tgz` Un compress this tar file using tar -xzf nakasig-jdq39-factory-0798439d.tgz cd nakasig-jdq39/ Then, reboot your device to the bootloader: adb reboot bootloader and then run: sh flash-all.sh from the folder where you have unzipped the drivers to. This will of course only work if you h

Answer (score 2):

If you recently installed **Ubuntu Touch** to the **Nexus 7** (using build **20130704.2**), the device may be (temporarily) **bricked**.

*.. endlessly cycling between the Google boot logo and a blank screen ..*

---

### **Step 1.**

Wait for the screen to go blank, and then ..

**Press and hold <kbd>Power</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> + <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> buttons, for 5-7 seconds.**

```
( This may take a few attempts. )
```

You should now be at the *Bootloader* screen ('green START' )

### **Step 2.**

**Use the <kbd>Volume Down</kbd> button twice**, to show 'Recovery Mode' (in red)

**Then press <kbd>Power</kbd>**, to restart in 'Recovery Mode'.

This will first show the Google logo for 4-6 seconds ..

Then change to Recovery Mode (with a Ubuntu logo in white circle).

### **Step 3.**

You should now be able to verify a USB connection.

**`adb devices`** should return 'recovery'

You can now download a fresh install to device.

Make sure **only** the target device is connected. *This will **not** verify the device attached, and will simply install software for a **Nexus 7** (grouper).*

**`phablet-flash -b -d grouper`**

---

***If this does not succeed, restore the device to Android (factory) settings.***

Answer (score 1):

what I would do at this point is flash a recovery image using `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` Use this link to download the recovery: [Nexus 7 Touch Recovery](http://download2.clockworkmod.com/recoveries/recovery-clockwork-touch-6.0.3.1-grouper.img)

Then download a rom: [Factory Images "nakasi" for Nexus 7 (Wi-Fi)](https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/nakasi-jdq39-factory-c317339e.tgz).

Boot to recovery and mount as USB storage. Copy the factory image ROM to the SD card.

Then use recovery to install Zip from SD card.